# Windows Phone - OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom in a UserControl

Tags: windows-phone-7, events

How can I get the OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom events to fire in a Windows Phone UserControl?  My UserControl is inside of a bound ListBox so there are a varying number of them, so I think I need to raise an event in the page and have the UserControls tap into and handle those events, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What? Is the UserControl in it's own page, or do you have a ListBox of usercontrol? Are you just trying to perform some action when they're displayed?

Comment: There is a page and on that page is a ListBox and inside of the ListBox is an instance of my UserControl.  The UserControl actually has in it an instance of the Microsoft Advertising control.  There is a problem with the ad control throwing an exception at times and the suggested solution to that is to do stuff on navigated to and from.  That's why I would like to tap into those events from the UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

`OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedFrom` are the methods raised by navigation service when a page is navigated these methods are a part of `Page` class.

For your problem, what you can do is you can make your user control to be derived from `Page` class and then setting the `Navigation` context and `Navigation` service for the same.